# show that $M/N$ is a torsion-free module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

> Let $M$ be an $R$-module and $N$ be the torsion sub-module. Then show that $M/N$ is a torsion-free $R$-module.

**Answer:**

Let $a \in M/N$,then $a=b+N, \ b \in M$.

Let $r \in R$, then $ra=r(b+N)=rb+rN=rb$, because $rN=0$ as $N$ torsion submodule.

Thus,

$ra=rb \neq N$ as $rb \neq 0$.

Thus $ra \neq N$ which implies $M/N$ is torsion-free.

But i think something is wrong.

Comment: It's false that $rN=\{0\}$ if $r$ is any element in $R$.  B.t.w., is $N$ `the` torsion submodule of $M$ or `a` torsion submodule?

Comment: @Bernard, if $R$ is a PID. Then what happens ?

Comment: PID or not, if $rN=\{0\}$ for any $r$, it implies $1\cdot N=\{0\}$, hence $ N=\{0\}$, so it is  $M $ itself which is torsion-free.